# failed to require a local gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

created a demo gem 
built it :

```
gem build control.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: process_controller
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: process_controller-0.0.1.gem
```

installed it:

```
gem install --local process_controller-0.0.1.gem
Successfully installed process_controller-0.0.1
1 gem installed
```

but I can't seem to require it :

```
irb (from the installed directory)
2.1.5 :001 > require 'process_controller'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- process_controller
    from /Users/partuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/partuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/partuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

also tried

```
require 'control' # since it's in the control directory
```

bundle show output:

```
bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.7.9)
  * process_controller (0.0.1)
```

here is a screen shot of the directory structure
http://cl.ly/image/2t1s331e273u

Comment: You don’t require a _gem_, you require a _file_ – is there a file named `process_controller.rb` inside the lib dir of the gem? Also: “since it's in the control directory” – what are you referring to here, the gem itself or the file? You might just need to `require 'control/process_controller'`.

Comment: thanks, I used require 'contol'

Comment: The convention is to have a file with the same name as the gem as the main file inside it, so it can look like you require a gem, but this is not what is actually happening (and is not always the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out you can't require the gem, you have to require the main file name.
in my case its:

```
require 'control'
```

thanks a lot @matt